# Expected declaration error( c error)

Tags: c

this is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main( int argc ,char *argv[] )
{
    FILE *fp;
    void filecopy( FILE * a, FILE *b )

    if (argc == 1)
    {
        filecopy(stdin,stdout);
    }

    else 
    {
        while(--argc > 0)
        {
            if ((fp = fopen(*++argv,"r")) == NULL)
            {   
                printf("no open".*argv);
            }
            else
            {
                filecopy(fp,stdout);
                fclose(fp);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void filecopy ( FILE *ifp ,FILE *ofp )
{
    int c;
    while ( (c = getc(ifp)) != EOF)
    {
        putc(c , ofp);
    }
}
```

these are my error:

```
con.c: In function 'filecopy':
con.c:8: error: expected declaration specifiers before 'if'
con.c:13: error: expected declaration specifiers before 'else'
con.c:29: error: expected declaration specifiers before 'return'
con.c:30: error: expected declaration specifiers before '}' token
con.c:33: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token
con.c:39: error: expected '{' at end of input
con.c: In function 'main':
con.c:39: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
```

Why am i getting these error please tell me ?
thank you
sudhanshu

Comment: Sorry actually its ("no open",*argv);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are missing a semi-colon.**

```
void filecopy( FILE * a, FILE *b );  /* Put semi-colon on the end! */
```

---

This line:

```
printf("no open".*argv);
```

Makes no sense.  What did you mean for it to do?

Comment: Even if you meant `printf("no open", *argv);` you would need a `%s` (or some other `%-formatter`) to justify passing the second parameter.

Answer (score 6):

You're missing a semicolon at the end of this line:

```
void filecopy( FILE * a, FILE *b )
```

This should be

```
void filecopy( FILE * a, FILE *b );
```

Because this is a function prototype.

Also, this line is not legal C:

```
printf("no open".*argv);
```

This should probably just be something like

```
printf("no open");
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The declaration needs to end with a semicolon

```
void filecopy( FILE * a, FILE *b );
```

(That's the declaration inside the main function, not the function definition which comes later.)